# Convert Future Function to Stream function in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, future

I'd like to get Stream out of Future...Please How to change Future in Stream.
For example a function that return a Future Movie:

```
Future < Movie > getMovieDetails(int id) async {
    Movie m = Movie.fromMap(await _service.v3.movies.getDetails(id, language: _lang));
    return m;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: check `Stream<T>.fromFuture()` constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your method as `async*` which returns a `Stream` instead of `Future`:

```
Stream<Movie> getMovieDetails(int id) async* {
  yield Movie.fromMap(await _service.v3.movies.getDetails(id, language: _lang));
}
```

You can then `yield` one or multiple values. When the method exits, the stream will be closed.

Read more here:
https://medium.com/@jelenaaa.lecic/what-are-sync-async-yield-and-yield-in-dart-defe57d06381